# How do I use pivot and group by together in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to get results which are in rows in the form of columns. I'm quite new to pivot in SQL would like to know how can I apply pivot in below case

CODE:

```
SELECT T.NAME, T.CODE, RN FROM(
SELECT NAME, CODE, SUM(PROFIT), ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME, SUM(PROFIT) DESC, CODE)RN 
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY NAME, CODE)T WHERE RN <= 3
```

MY CURRENT RESULT:

```
NAME CODE RN
A    XX   1
A    YY   2
A    ZZ   3
B    XX   1
B    PP   2
C    GH   1
C    JU   2
C    GQ   3
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
NAME 1  2  3
A    XX YY ZZ
B    XX PP NULL
C    GH JU GQ
```

Comment: Can we have your actual code please, or at least something runnable? Some sample data would also help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.
just `PIVOT()` as below. Encapsulate your current query as a CTE or derived table

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT T.NAME, T.CODE, RN 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT NAME, CODE, SUM(PROFIT), 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME, SUM(PROFIT) DESC, CODE)RN 
        FROM TABLE1
        GROUP BY NAME, CODE
    )T 
    WHERE RN <= 3
) D
PIVOT
(
    MAX(CODE)
    FOR RN IN ([1] , [2], [3])
) P
```

Comment: You don't technically need the `WHERE` filter. Values not listed in the `PIVOT` clause for the column immediately before the `IN` get discarded anyway.